# В статье не отображается строка кода с подключением библиотеки

Tags: html

В тексте статью надо указать кусок кода с С++. Все хорошо, но в первой строке, где подключается библиотека (выглядит она в коде статьи вот так):

```
<p><code style="color: #006468">#include <AFMotor.h></code></p>
```

отображается только "#include ", а AFMotor.h в треугольных скобках пропадает.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте &lt для того, чтобы показать "<" и &gt для того, чтобы показать ">"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<code>
#include &ltiostream&gt
</code>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Точно. Огромное спасибо.